# sqlzoo joinII exercise - movie databases 4a

Tags: sql

This is question is [sqlzoo](http://sqlzoo.net/), and I wrote following code, but I feel it is too redundant

```
SELECT year, freq 
FROM (SELECT yr AS year,count(title) AS freq
FROM movie, actor, casting
WHERE name= 'John Travolta'
AND movie.id=movieid
AND actor.id=actorid
GROUP BY yr) AS a
WHERE freq=(
SELECT MAX(freq)
FROM (SELECT yr AS year,count(title) AS freq
FROM movie, actor, casting
WHERE name= 'John Travolta'
AND movie.id=movieid
AND actor.id=actorid
GROUP BY yr) AS b
)
```

why cannot it be like this?

```
SELECT year, freq 
FROM (SELECT yr AS year,count(title) AS freq
FROM movie, actor, casting
WHERE name= 'John Travolta'
AND movie.id=movieid
AND actor.id=actorid
GROUP BY yr) AS a
WHERE freq=(
SELECT MAX(freq)
FROM a
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this it may be helpful to use CTE's (Common Table Expression). That's the only way you can re-use a subquery. Look how you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to find the largest frequency. I have also updated the old school `FROM A, B, C WHERE ...` to the new school `FROM A INNER JOIN B ...` (I'm not 100% sure the JOIN criteria are correct though.)

```
WITH a AS
(
    SELECT 
        yr AS year, 
        COUNT(title) AS freq
    FROM 
        movie
    INNER JOIN 
        casting ON movie.id = casting.movieid
    INNER JOIN 
        actor ON actor.id = casting.actorid
    WHERE 
        name = 'John Travolta'
    GROUP BY 
        yr),
b AS
(
     SELECT 
         year, freq,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY freq DESC) as RowNum
     FROM a
)
SELECT year, freq 
FROM  b
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are writing sub-queries the inner ones are evaluated first and then the outer queries.In your second query you are using alias "a" which doesn't exist actually.That is the reason you will get an error in the second query and you cannot use it.The first query is the correct one syntactically.